# Google sheets Get Duration from a string

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to get the duration dynamically from a string of text, like the example shown in the image example of input and output: [Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WC3u1x1740yqhuZTfa9s3ipO-eTYc2WFflP7lFgQZHI/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

I did try *`REGEXEXTRACT`* but it did not have lookahead or lookbehind features. 
i would like to get days, hours, minutes as an intermediate step and the final duration.
minutes as decimal portions of 100 or 60 either way is acceptable.

Comment: An example sheet would be nice :)

Comment: You will likely receive more replies from the volunteer contributor community here if you share a link to a spreadsheet that already has your data in it; otherwise, you're expecting that the volunteers here will start their own spreadsheet and hand enter your data before then putting in the time to consider how to solve the issue. In addition, it's unclear whether you really just need the final duration data in hours (with the previous three serving as intermediate/helper columns), or if you actually need all four columns of results. Please clarify.

Comment: ^ +1. Now if you do that, we can also show you how to centralize your formulas to 1 place with `arrayformula` for example, as opposed to talking about general ideas with `regexexract`

Comment: Your "rules" are also not clear. For instance, 54 minutes is not equal to `0.54 h`. It would be 54/60 or `0.9 h`. Your other "durations" that include minutes are equally set up to show the minutes simply as decimal portions of 100, not of 60. Please clarity.

Comment: @ErikTyler: I would say duration is another question. I was only going to point that out when OP replies so it's one thing at a time ;)

Comment: The OP's post starts "I want to get the duration..." So I assume that the duration may be the main goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You can do this on a single cell:

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1;"\d+ days|day");REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\d+ day|days");"\d+");"")`

Replace `A1` with your cell, and `day|days` with whatever unit you want.

Hopefully this can solve your issue.

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\d+ ((days|day))")` Returns two cells days|days like the `SPLIT` function does and where doesn't contain day or days show this error `Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\d+ ((days|day))" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "1 hour 1 min".`

Comment: You don't need helper cell in implementation. You can just wrap `regexextract()` twice. (Being able to combine helper cells by composing functions is usually how it turns out.) But good on you to describe the solution with helper cells. That makes the solution clear

Comment: There, I fix it :) Tell me if that solves it

Comment: @Benliam12: It should. Neither of us has the example sheet to test tho ;). Btw, you don't need to match the plurals, since `\d+ day` is contained in `\d+ days`

Comment: @Benliam12 It worked perfectly for the days, and i replicat it for the rest of the columns i would like to get a breakdown way day|days are switched in the following `REGEXEXTRACT` function

Comment: If somebody could combine it with `ARRAYFORMULA` that would be really beneficial.

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).